# ClassNotFoundException: spray.json.JsonFormat

Tags: scala, spray-json

I'm trying to use spray-json.

The following test code throws `ClassNotFoundException: spray.json.JsonFormat`:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val ast = List(1, 2, 3).toJson
    println(ast.compactPrint)
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using sbt's `package` command for generating the final jar file. It apparently doesn't package the dependencies altogether.

I fixed this by using the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the class `spray.json.JsonFormat` is not found at run time.

Make sure this class is part of your run time dependencies.

Comment: For thoose who usually got confused by this error, your directives are not instantly obvious. How can one check the class path? What are the places which one need to check out to nail down the problem with this specific class? What should I do if spray IS on class path (version mismatch?), etc

Comment: Thanks. How can do that with sbt? I currently use the `package` command to create my jar.